# Firebase is returning an empty array when trying to console.log query. React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Trying to add each object that is seen inside the 'specific' collection to an array of objects, each object is a chapter. Right now, when I try and print notes to console, I just get an empty array. I used very similar code for another part of this project and it works just fine, the only thing that is different about this one is the directory of the query so I'm assuming its something wrong with that.

```
where the state is managed:

    const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);


The function trying to get the query:

    const getTakeaways = () => {
        const snapshot = db.collection('users').doc(userEmail).
            collection('books').doc(item.title).
            collection('specific').onSnapshot((doc) => {
                let tempNotes = []
                doc.forEach(obj => {
                    tempNotes.push(obj.data())

                })
                setNotes(tempNotes)
                console.log('notes', notes)
                console.log('tempnotes', tempNotes)
            })
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        getTakeaways()
    }, [])
```

Both of the console logs are returning empty arrays.

Heres an example firebase path:

```
/users/Email@email.com/books/How to win friends and influence people/specific/chapter1
```

note that 'chapter1' is a document with an array of strings inside

Thank you!

Comment: *Both of the console logs are returning empty arrays.* - there's no console.log's in the code you posted - the location of the console.log's is important

Comment: my bad, note I have tried placing the logs in a separate test function accessed via button, and that had the same result. I updated the post with the version with the logs.

Comment: Could you post your whole data structure on Firestore?